# Getting error when Installing Modx on GoDaddy - 500 internal server error

Tags: hosting, web-hosting, modx-revolution

I'm trying to install a ModX Revolution on a new hosting(Never did it before). The hosting is by GoDaddy (a windows server with a Plesk panel).
 I uploaded the modx installation files - setup and core folders, into the httpdocs directory and gave the core folder a needed permission. Now, when i'm entering to the: 'mysitename.net/setup' I'm getting the modx installation menu with language selection as it should be. But when i'm hitting the 'select' button after choosing any language, the page redirecting to the 'mysitename.net/setup/?' = 500 Internal Server Error.
Maybe some body have an idea what am i doing wrong and how to fix this issue?

Comment: check the requirements more in depth - https://docs.modx.com/revolution/2.x/getting-started/server-requirements
Also try to install it via hosting interface with things like Softaculous instead of directly uploading files to the server. And if you totally stuck ask the hosting's support to assist.

Comment: A 500 error produces some sort of log entry. Find that error log and paste it here, then we can help you. Without that there are simply too many things that could have caused this.

Comment: Any news, i got same error :(

Comment: Didn't find solution on goDaddy, so i changed the hosting provider... I think that maybe the problem was because of a windows server that i selected.. If you already chose windows instead linux, maybe they may change the deal to a lunux or something... The best is to speak with their support.